# ogr2ogr - Shapefile database SQL query; missing .cpg and .xml

Tags: python, gdal, pyqgis, ogr2ogr

I am using gdal and ogr2ogr to perform a SQL query on a database of shapefiles with the code below. The geoprocessing works and the appropriate shapefile is extracted from the query, but when I print `boundary` it shows `0` and the `.cpg` and `.xml` files are missing after the geoprocessing is completed. I also a get a warning: `Value of field SHAPE_Area of feauture 0 not successfully written. Possible due to too larger number with respect to field width`

```
import gdal
import subprocess

directory = r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_test\Water_Districts\Water_Districts.shp"
output_shp = r"E:\IrrigatedLands\FC_qgis\boundary.shp"

boundary = subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-where", "NAME = 'Cache La Poudre River'", output_shp, directory])

print boundary
```

Comment: Did you manage to open the output shape file ?

Comment: What is the version of your ogr2ogr? At least new versions do write .prj. If the source projection is not recognised automatically adding -a_srs epsg:xxxx may help.

Comment: when adding `"-a_srs", "epsg:xxxx"` before `"-where"` and after `"ogr2ogr"` the following error is shown: `failed to lookup OUM code 0`

Comment: I did not mean xxxx literally. Use the code of your projection, like EPSG:4326.